# Track generated file sizes on github using Travis-CI

Tags: javascript, github, travis-ci

I'd like to track the size of my minified JavaScript bundle as it's affected by pull requests on GitHub:

[image: combined JS code size changes by +0.68%]

I'd like to see the size changes for a generated file in a GitHub status on each commit that Travis-CI builds. This would be similar to how coveralls.io and other tools track code coverage as it changes.

How can I do this? Are there existing tools? Is it simple to write my own?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to have code coverage for javascript?

Comment: No. I already have code coverage for JavaScript. What I'd like is a GitHub "check" which reports how the size of a build artifact changes.

Answer (score 8):

GitHub provides a [simple API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) for posting statuses on commits.

By putting a GitHub OAuth token in a [Travis-CI environment variable](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings), you can run a `curl` command to post the status:

```
filesize=$(wc -c < path-to-script.min.js | sed 's/ //g')
curl -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  --data '{"context": "file size", "description": "'$filesize' bytes", "state": "success"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG/statuses/$TRAVIS_COMMIT
```

Calculating the change in file size resulting from a pull request is trickier. I wound up creating a Python script to do this, which you can find in the [travis-weigh-in](https://github.com/danvk/travis-weigh-in) repo. With it, you'd just run this in your Travis build:

```
python weigh_in.py path-to-script.min.js
```

And it will produce commit statuses like the one in the question's screenshot.